# How to use fingerprint reader on Debian 10 to login as root and login session?

Tags: linux, usb, debian, firmware, fingerprint

I have Debian 10, and a fingerprint reader.

I am able to use with

- `fprintd-enroll` => add a finger print
- `fprintd-verify` => test the previously added finger print
- `fprintd-list $(whoami)` => show my fingerprints

The last one produce:

```
dka@dka:[~]: fprintd-list dka
found 1 devices
Device at /net/reactivated/Fprint/Device/0
Using device /net/reactivated/Fprint/Device/0
Fingerprints for user dka on Synaptics Sensors (press):
 - #0: right-index-finger
```

This is my USB device:

```bsh
dka@dka:[~]: lsusb | grep syna -i
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 06cb:00bd Synaptics, Inc.
```

Is there a GUI I can easely get for Debian ?

I use cinnamon, I want to use fingerprint for login into login as root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here. It had helped me out on a ThinkPad from Lenovo, but can be used on every PC with a fingerprint reader.

-> https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/enable-fingerprint-scanner-support-on-linux/

Comment: Please include essential instructions in the answer to make it self-contained and leave the link as original source. Right now if the link goes bad, your answer will become useless for future visitors with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Worked completely for me on Debian testing (12.0) and https://Frame.work/ laptop 1st gen:
https://wiki.debian.org/SecurityManagement/fingerprint%20authentication

To make it easier, here is short output from the source. Tho without GUI/WUI, but with CLI/TUI, works perfectly! ALWAYS

```
apt install fprintd libpam-fprintd
fprintd-enroll # Tap finger multiple times, to get as much angles as possibile
su -c "pam-auth-update"
```